# I am unable to run this command in (.format) in Python .... please guide me the correct synatx with coding

Tags: python-3.x

```
a = 12345.98521466
print('The value of a is :{}'.format(a:0.3f))
```

This code is giving syntax error.What is the correct syntax for printing upto  3 decimal places
in  `format()`?

Comment: "The person who downvoted you should have given an explanation for their downvote." No they shouldn't. Please don't give people wrong expectations. If *someone* wants to to provide feedback for improvement, they will.

Comment: The `:0.3f` belongs into the format string placeholder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be serveral ways. I provided two ways to print the value using `format`, as follows:

```py
a = 12345.98521466

# solution 1: using f-string
print(f'The value of a is :{a:0.3f}')  # The value of a is :12345.985

# solution 2: using .format
print('The value of a is :{:0.3f}'.format(a))  # The value of a is :12345.985
```

For more information about printing foramt, please refer to: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html